# Error in Database.EnsureCreated() while using Entity Framework with Sqlite in Xamarin

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm using Entity Framework in Xamarin Forms that uses sqlite. When I debug `Xamarin.Android`, everything is ok, also in debugging Xamarin.iOs with iPhone simulator, it works fine.

My `DbContext` is:

```
public class DB:DbContext
{
    // Tables
    private readonly string _databasepath;

    public DB(string databasepath)
    {
        _databasepath = databasepath;
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"filename={_databasepath}");
    }
}
```

But when I run my project on an iOS device, this exception will thrown at `Database.EnsureCreated()`:

> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ResultOperators.Internal.TrackingExpressionNode' threw an exception.

What's wrong?

Comment: Database.EnsureCreated(); isn't it supposed to be called on DBContext object?

Comment: In the debugger, look at your Exception object. You have mentioned here its message (ex.Message). Try to check its InnerException member. Probably there you will find something more meaningful.

Comment: The linker cannot see everything that's required, because there's no hints from the library to help it, so code used only thru reflection is removed.

The attached sample works for me when when I add this line: [assembly: Preserve (typeof (System.Linq.Queryable), AllMembers = true)]

to the Main.cs file of the main project. It merely tells the linker that all members of System.Linq.Queryable should be preserved even if static analysis does not see them used by any code.