# How to enable migration in EntityFramework Core Sqlite

Tags: xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core-migrations

I have Dbset and creating database like this. When first time db is created then after I add column in dbset, then the migration does not work the table column is not found. Please help me how I can enable EF Core Sqlite migrations in Xamarin Forms.

```
public  BaseSQLRespository(string databasePath)
{
    try
    {
        _databasePath = databasePath;

        Database.EnsureCreated();

        // bool IsDatabaseCreated= ;
        // Settings.IsDatabaseCreatedSettings = IsDatabaseCreated;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    try
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(string.Format("Filename={0}", _databasePath));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you created a migration for your new column using the `add-migration` command, you can enable the execution of migrations at runtime by calling the `Migrate()` method instead of `EnsureCreated()`. The docs for the method can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.migrate?view=efcore-2.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions_Migrate_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_).

As per Microsoft's documentation, the `Migrate` method is incompatible with the `EnsureCreated` method which actually bypasses the migrations when creating the database schema - so in your case you will have to delete the old database (uninstall the app or clear it's data) before trying the new code.

> Don't call `EnsureCreated()` before `Migrate()`. `EnsureCreated()` bypasses Migrations to create the schema, which causes `Migrate()` to fail.

Source: [EF Core - Apply migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#apply-migrations-at-runtime)

Comment: I checked the given source and EnsureCreated is not mentioned there (it might have been in the past). Nonetheless, your post has led me to finding other sources and also solving a long lasting issue i had, so i wish i could give more +1s. If you would like to add this as an additional [source](https://thedatafarm.com/data-access/ef7-ensurecreated-vs-migrate-methods/) it might help others as well.

Comment: In case my source will go away, here is the resume of it and a link to a relevant issue raised on  [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/3160)

Comment: _EnsureCreated totally bypasses migrations and just creates the schema for you, you can’t mix this with migrations. EnsureCreated is designed for testing or rapid prototyping where you are ok with dropping and re-creating the database each time. If you are using migrations and want to have them automatically applied on app start, then you can use context.Database.Migrate() instead._

Answer (score 1):

To add an initial migration, run the following command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add YourNameOfMigration
```

Next, apply the migration to the database to create the schema:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

[Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#update-the-database)

Every time when you add a new field to the model you should add migration and apply it to DB.

Answer (score -2):

i guess your configuration is wrong, you shouldn't call `Database.EnsureCreated();` in ctor because `OnConfiguring()` is not called yet and your database is not initialized.

you can create a method which called once your serviceProvider is started.

```
   public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
            var context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<BaseSQLRespository>();//use your service provider any thing which you can get your current created `BaseSQLRespository`
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();//once call when your app is started. (it is up to you which method you used to call)
   ...
   ...
   }
```

**In Addition**, here is similar topic and different solution,
 you can check: [Error in Database.EnsureCreated() while using Entity Framework with Sqlite in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52690332/error-in-database-ensurecreated-while-using-entity-framework-with-sqlite-in-xa)